# Import contribution to github from bitbucket

Tags: github, version-control, bitbucket

I just got a new job recently, and all repos of their projects are on BitBucket.
I used to use a lot GitHub, so I was wondering if there is a way to sync contribution between the two.

I have already tried https://github.com/jrm2k6/contwidgetor. It seems like a way to do it but didn't work for me somehow, and there is only limited support of it.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Contributions Importer for GitHub](https://github.com/miromannino/Contributions-Importer-For-Github)

It copies all commits from source git repositories to a mock git repository. Each copied commit will report the same commit date, but the original code is not copied, neither the commit message.

The mock code is generated using the same language of the original source repository.

For example, I have a mock repository on my profile that reports all the activities of all my private repositories.

Comment: Doesn't GitHub's own importer add to contributions based on the imported repo's git history?

Comment: @PetroCliff it's to combine contributions from bitbucket and github on one graph

Answer (score 5):

You can at least manually mirror any Git BitBucket repo from BitBucket to GitHub:

```
git clone --mirror http://user@bitbucket/user/repo.git
git remote add github http://user@github.com/user/repo.git
git push --mirror github
```

(Create an empty repo on GitHub side first)

Then, on demand, you can go into your local clone, do a fetch, and then a git `push --mirror github` again to sync new commits.

Comment: Thanks for answering man, you are right, this is at least what I can do, but repo on BitBucket are all private and I dont actually have permission to clone. I may need some other ways.

Comment: @IsaacGuan I agree: private repos are supposed to remain private, meaning to be cloned only within the company private network. A private repo cloned elsewhere is no longer private.

Comment: This worked for me. You also have to make sure your email that you're committing with is added to your github profile. Then the commits show up for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situations, so I just whipped a node script together. I think it's more simple (implementation wise) than the solution posted by mir88.

The program then makes a shadow repository on GitHub. Each Bitbucket repository is represented by a file, and each Bitbucket commit is reflected by the Bitbucket commit hash.
The Bitbucket hashes are added backwards in time so the match the point in time when the original commit was made on Bitbucket.

Should be easy to change to your exact needs.

Feel free to check it out: [Bitbucket 2 GitHub Activity Sync](https://github.com/SV3A/bBucket2gHub).